# Send three HTML select elements as one to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

all! I have the below snippet in my code. I am trying the `console.log` to show `{"selectDays":"13","selectMonths":"8","selectYear":"2018"}`as JSON format, but in only 1 string, for example: `{"dateTimeString:2018/08/13"}` in format "yyyy-mm-dd" is this possible, can someone please help me?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
  var qntYears = 4;
  var selectYear = $("#selectYears");
  var selectMonth = $("#selectMonths");
  var selectDay = $("#selectDays");
  var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  
    
  for (var y = 0; y < qntYears; y++){
    let date = new Date(currentYear);
    var yearElem = document.createElement("option");
    yearElem.value = currentYear 
    yearElem.textContent = currentYear;
    selectYear.append(yearElem);
    currentYear--;
  } 

  for (var m = 0; m < 12; m++){
      let monthNum = new Date(2018, m).getMonth();
      let month =  monthNames[monthNum];
      var monthElem = document.createElement("option");
      monthElem.value = monthNum+1; 
      monthElem.textContent = month;
      selectMonth.append(monthElem);
    }

    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var day = d.getDate();

    selectYear.val(year); 
    selectYear.bind("change", AdjustDays);  
    selectMonth.val(month);    
    selectMonth.bind("change", AdjustDays);

    AdjustDays();
    selectDay.val(day);
    
    function AdjustDays(){
      var year = selectYear.val();
      var month = parseInt(selectMonth.val());
      selectDay.empty();
      
      //get the last day, so the number of days in that month
      var days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate(); 
      
      //lets create the days of that month
      for (var d = 1; d <= days; d++){
        var dayElem = document.createElement("option");
        dayElem.value = d; 
        dayElem.textContent = d;
        selectDay.append(dayElem);
      }
    }    

   var dateTimeString = year + '/' + month +'/' + day;
   console.log(dateTimeString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectDays" name="selectDays"></select>     

<select id="selectMonths" name="selectMonths"></select>

<select  id="selectYears" class="input-year" name="selectYear"></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have them wrapped in a form, then add a `submit` event listener on the form which will cancel the default action and manually make your call:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="selectDays" ...>
  <select id="selectMonths" ...>
  <select id="selectYears" ...>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel the normal submit
  const data = { 
    selectDays: $('#selectDays').val(),
    selectMonths: $('#selectMonths').val(),
    selectYears: $('#selectYears').val()
  };

  $.ajax('http://example.com/my-url', {
    method: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json"
  });
}).done(() => { /* do something when done */ });
```

This will override the default form submitting action to instead gather up the data and send it as a single JSON object in your call.

If you need to tweak the values you are sending, just tweak them in the constructed `data` object as needed.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I've forgotten about form completely.

Comment: No problem. Technically, you don't absolutely have to have a form, but it is best practice and makes it a little easier.